# JMeter 500- Internal Error while running 100 users for the first time in Non-GUI mode

Tags: jmeter

While running Jmeter in non-gui mode for 100 users for the first time after the restart of the server, it shows an "Internal Error" message for a single  save thread (other 99 save threads have passed).

This error is when run for the first time.Later it passes 100 users any N number of times.

But when the same is done in manual testing (ie; saving 100 users) there is no error.

What could be the issue.

[image: Jmeter Request Screenshot][image: Jmeter Response Screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.6.1)

> **6.6.1.  500 Internal Server Error**

> The 500 (Internal Server Error) status code indicates that the server
> encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling
> the request.

In general all [HTTP status codes 5xx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors) indicate a **server error**, so there is nothing to do with your JMeter script, you need to look into your server logs to identify the root cause of the issue on the **server side**.

It might be the case that the server gets overloaded and cannot handle 100 concurrent users due to one of the following reasons:

- incorrect configuration of the server infrastructure (application server, database configuration settings, etc.), make sure that [all the components of your application are properly configured for high load](https://stackify.com/web-performance-optimization/)
- lack of resources (CPU, RAM, Network and/or Disk IO, swap, sockets, etc.), make sure to monitor essential resources usage during the test execution, it can be done using i.e. [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)
- it might also be the case your application uses [inefficient or too complex algorithms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation), it worth running a test with [performance profiling tools telemetry enabled](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_performance_analysis_tools), this is probably the best way of identifying the bottleneck